# Android studio jump to builld.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, module

I'm working on a multi-module project in android studio and using android-project-view mode.
And it's not handy to go to the bottom of the project structure and look for a proper `build.gradle` file.
Is there any hotkey to jump to the module-build file?
Something simular to **Select-opened file**[image]

Comment: You can try using Search Everywhere. Press Shift twice, type build.gradle, and select the needed file.

Comment: but if you have 40+ modules in a project that is not really handy

Comment: Agree, I am also looking for similar solution. Its really painful to search module build.gradle when your project has many modules. Ideally the best solution is to show all gradles files in respective module  when you are in Android View.